# Different favicon icon is showing in google search result

Tags: google, favicon

I have a blogger blog. My blog's favicon icon is showing different icon in Google search result. But it's showing the correct one in Chrome tab.

My favicon ico link is:

```
<link href='https://www.example.in/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Are you searching using a desktop computer or using a mobile device? I only see favicons used in the SERPs on mobile. There are some requirements you can find here. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858?hl=en Also, how long has it been? Google is very very slow. Why? Because the Internet is so vast. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, im searching using a mobile device. I have two blogs in blogger. And favicon icon of my blog 2 is showings my blog 1's favicon icon in search result. My favicon icon link is also showing soft 404 in search console.